# Reproject with shifted central meridian - dateline gap in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, antimeridian

I have reprojected a file of global ocean zoning to Winkel III shifting the central meridian to -180 to center it on the Pacific using ArcGIS 10.5. Doing so, a gap at the dateline appears:
[image]

In a closeup, it's actually a line and a gap:
[image]

The whole file remains one polygon though. I've tried the Integrate tool but no success. I wonder which tool to use instead, if I am making a mistake regarding the reprojection or if there is any cosmetic fix to make the line disappear (but keep other outlines) in maps?

Comment: Did you try the Dissolve tool?

Answer (score 1):

Normally I use this for a similar looking display issue East-West across the map, but you could try moving the wrap parameter the .prj file. (e.g. `+lon_wrap=-180`) See wrap parameter explanation [here](https://proj.org/usage/projections.html#longitude-wrapping).

Edit:

I do this by creating a custom projection. Then you should be able to customize/write your own .prj file. See the documentation links for Arc and QGIS below.

[Arc link](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008500) // [QGIS Link](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. How would I move the wrap parameter? I am not familiar with Python in ArcGIS and cannot open the .prj in any meaningful way either.

Comment: You can always open .prj using notepad and take a look at what's there 

Comment: @Lisa your link to the wrap parameter is broken, can you fix it please?

Comment: @Hornbydd updated the link